# Dates not printing using logback.xml

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I am really stuck on this issue. I am using Spring MVC application and using following dependencies in my web application

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is the my logback.xml file, **but when I deploy my application I don't see any dates are printing, only time is printing on Eclipse console. Any help how to fixed this?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- By default, encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Send debug messages to a file at "c:/jcg.log" -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>c:/jcg.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>c:/jcg.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>2MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.javacodegeeks.examples.logbackexample.beans" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Is this something getting called at run time? I can see this file is not getting called.** Also for non-web application it works fine, but for web application it don't works

Comment: where in your project is your logback.xml?

Comment: Hi Sheltem - It's in src/main/resources/configs/logback.xml location. It looks like it should be in src/main/resources only, but if I want to use src/main/resources/configs/, What else I need to change? Why only it works in src/main/resources folders?  Regards, Neha

Comment: You appear to be using Maven. That packages the contents of src/main/resources into your deployment by default: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html Any locations not mentioned in that link would have to be explicitly configured to be packaged as well (e. g. via the maven-resources-plugin)